# Android Exception "The specified child already has a parent..."

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I m getting exception as follow. Can anybody help me?

> 06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

```
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1970)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1822)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1802)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at com.mVisum_philips.MainECGActivity.popupEvent(MainECGActivity.java:628)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at com.mVisum_philips.MainECGActivity$1.onClick(MainECGActivity.java:195)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        06-16 11:32:48.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9223):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Source code for *screen_pop_up.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/headerLin" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Done"></Button>
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
                        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/h_scale" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="15sp"></Button>
                        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/v_scale" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="14sp"></Button>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
           </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linLin" android:layout_height="300sp" android:layout_width="250sp">
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Source code where i m getting the exception is as follows:

```
final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(MainECGActivity.this);
                myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.screen_pop_up);
                myDialog.setTitle("My Dialog");

                LinearLayout myLin = (LinearLayout) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.linLin);
                **myLin.addView(ECGField.get(0));**

                myDialog.setCancelable(true);
                Button button = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    myDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                myDialog.show();
```

I have gone through many threads here but I am missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how to help without a bit of code..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A view can only have a single parent. The view that you are adding (I am guessing re-using) is already part of another view hierarchy. If you really want to reuse it (I would suggest you probably dont) then you have to detach it from its parent in its existing view hierarchy.

whatever is returned by ECGField.get(0) is already in a view hierarchy.