# Multiple TextViews in ScrollView at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a bunch of TextViews at runtime to a scrollview but I get `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView on the child's parent first`.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**testapp**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TextView[] data;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    View layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

            .......................................

    data = new TextView[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        data[i] = new TextView(this);
        data[i].setText("data = " + i);


        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(data[i]);
    }

    setContentView(layout);

}
```

Comment: youre trying to reinvent ListView?

Comment: why your using this setContentView(layout) again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `setContentView()` twice in a single `Activity` like this. That's the problem.
Look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6371421/603744):

> A view can only have a single parent. The view that you are adding (I am guessing re-using) is already part of another view hierarchy. If you really want to reuse it (I would suggest you probably don't) then you have to detach it from its parent in its existing view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is of layout variable.

it already has a parent ScrollView view as per XML now when you are using this  setContentView(layout); so this try to add layout in different parent ..

Comment: Sorry but I think we can have setContentView()  twice http://www.androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/38205.html