# Android: You must call removeView() on the child's parent first 2

Tags: android, parent-child

I have a problem in `Android` creating a table adding rows dynamically. The error message is:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first

But why?

```
    void setCalendario(List<ArrayList<String>> l){
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.list_tableLayout1);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.removeAllViews();
    tr.setPadding(0,10,0,10);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    TextView tv_item1 = new TextView(this);
    TextView tv_item2 = new TextView(this);
    TextView tv_item3 = new TextView(this);
    for (ArrayList<String> al : l){
        int i = 0;
        for(String s : al){
            if (i == 0){
                i++;
                tv_item1.setText(s);
                tv_item1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }
            if (i == 1){
                tv_item2.setText(s);
                tv_item2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 2){
                tv_item3.setText(s);
                tv_item3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tr.addView(tv_item1);
                tr.addView(tv_item2);
                tr.addView(tv_item3);
                table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

the xml code:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.MSca.gorhinos.Calendario$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>


</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help to resolve exception "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371277/help-to-resolve-exception-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-ca)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you once create tv_item1, tv_item2 and tv_item3. Then in cycle for all ArrayList you adding this views

```
tr.addView(tv_item1);
tr.addView(tv_item2);
tr.addView(tv_item3);
```

At the second iteration you already add tv_item1 to tr. And you want to do it again. I guess you need just transfer this lines to cycle:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.removeAllViews();
tr.setPadding(0,10,0,10);
tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TextView tv_item1 = new TextView(this);
TextView tv_item2 = new TextView(this);
TextView tv_item3 = new TextView(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a for-loop to add the same references to `TextView`s to your `TableRow`. So in the next iteration of the loop, the **same** objects are added to the `TableRow` (or `TableLayout`), again! They already have a parent by then.

Try to initialize the `TableRow` and `TextView` objects *inside* the (outer)for-loop.

**EDIT:** Modified your code.

```
void setCalendario(List<ArrayList<String>> l) {
    // Here we initialize the objects we re-initialize every iteration of the loop
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.list_tableLayout1);
    for (ArrayList<String> al : l) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    // I can't believe a freshly initialized TableRow object has views attached...
        tr.removeAllViews();
        tr.setPadding(0,10,0,10);
    // Not sure why these layout params are needed already, as they are specified
    // when adding this TableRow to the TableLayout object as well.
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TextView tv_item1 = new TextView(this);
        TextView tv_item2 = new TextView(this);
        TextView tv_item3 = new TextView(this);
        int i = 0;
        for(String s : al) {
            if (i == 0) {
                i++;
                tv_item1.setText(s);
                tv_item1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                tv_item2.setText(s);
                tv_item2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                tv_item3.setText(s);
                tv_item3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tr.addView(tv_item1);
                tr.addView(tv_item2);
                tr.addView(tv_item3);
                table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: thx, finally i have understand this parent's problem

p.s. the i++; must put to the end of cycles ops

Answer (score 0):

because you are trying to put the same textView many times. you can use it only once, so you have to instantiate it again and again :

```
// you remove the definition of the text views here and you put it inside the loop
    for (ArrayList<String> al : l){
        int i = 0;
        for(String s : al){
 TextView tv_item2 = new TextView(this);
TextView tv_item1 = new TextView(this);
TextView tv_item3 = new TextView(this);
            if (i == 0){
                i++;

                tv_item1.setText(s);
                tv_item1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }
            if (i == 1){

                tv_item2.setText(s);
                tv_item2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 2){

                tv_item3.setText(s);
                tv_item3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tr.addView(tv_item1);
                tr.addView(tv_item2);
                tr.addView(tv_item3);
                table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is not the best way to do it, you should may be creat a methode that takes your "i" as parameter and returns a TextView (with gravity center ... and your staff).